# How to use DrawLine in C++ (DirectX Graphics)

Tags: directx, kinect, direct2d

```
// Draw a grid background.
        int width = static_cast<int>(rtSize.width);
        int height = static_cast<int>(rtSize.height);

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 10)
        {
            m_pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
                D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(x), 0.0f),
                D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<FLOAT>(x), rtSize.height),
                m_pLightSlateGrayBrush,
                0.5f
                );
        }
```

This is the sample in the documentation. I've included "D2d1.h", I just don't know how to create a "m_pRenderTarget". I'm writing a Kinect project, I want to draw a line on the image. I'm really new, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you see this page?

[Create an ID2D1HwndRenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd535473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#step_3__create_an_id2d1hwndrendertarget)

The quick start tutorial has a detail steps of how to use Direct2D.

You can also download the Windows SDK, the samples contains Direct2D demo which has the full steps of how to create Direct2D render target

I have write a program to draw a rectangle, with a little change, it can draw a line, just for  your reference

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <D2D1.h>

#define SAFE_RELEASE(P) if(P){P->Release() ; P = NULL ;}

ID2D1Factory*           g_pD2DFactory   = NULL; // Direct2D factory
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget*  g_pRenderTarget = NULL; // Render target
ID2D1SolidColorBrush*   g_pBlackBrush   = NULL; // A black brush, reflect the line color

VOID CreateD2DResource(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (!g_pRenderTarget)
    {
        HRESULT hr ;

        hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &g_pD2DFactory) ;
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "Create D2D factory failed!", "Error", 0) ;
            return ;
        }

        // Obtain the size of the drawing area
        RECT rc ;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc) ;

        // Create a Direct2D render target
        hr = g_pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(
            hWnd, 
            D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left,rc.bottom - rc.top)
            ), 
            &g_pRenderTarget
            ) ;
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "Create render target failed!", "Error", 0) ;
            return ;
        }

        // Create a brush
        hr = g_pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(
            D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black),
            &g_pBlackBrush
            ) ;
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "Create brush failed!", "Error", 0) ;
            return ;
        }
    }
}

VOID DrawLine(HWND hwnd)
{
    CreateD2DResource(hwnd) ;

    g_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw() ;

    // Clear background color to White
    g_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));

    // Draw Rectangle
    g_pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
        D2D1::Point2F(100.0f, 100.0f),
        D2D1::Point2F(500.0f, 500.0f),
        g_pBlackBrush
        );

    HRESULT hr = g_pRenderTarget->EndDraw() ;
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Draw failed!", "Error", 0) ;
        return ;
    }
}


VOID Cleanup()
{
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pRenderTarget) ;
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pBlackBrush) ;
    SAFE_RELEASE(g_pD2DFactory) ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)   
{
    switch (message)    
    {
    case   WM_PAINT:
        DrawLine(hwnd) ;
        return 0 ;

    case WM_KEYDOWN: 
        { 
            switch( wParam ) 
            { 
            case VK_ESCAPE: 
                SendMessage( hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0 ); 
                break ; 
            default: 
                break ; 
            } 
        } 
        break ; 

    case WM_DESTROY: 
        Cleanup(); 
        PostQuitMessage( 0 ); 
        return 0; 
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow )
{

    WNDCLASSEX winClass ;

    winClass.lpszClassName = "Direct2D";
    winClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    winClass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    winClass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    winClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
    winClass.hIcon         = NULL ;
    winClass.hIconSm       = NULL ;
    winClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    winClass.hbrBackground = NULL ;
    winClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    winClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    winClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&winClass))   
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL, TEXT( "This program requires Windows NT!" ), "error", MB_ICONERROR) ;
        return 0 ;  
    }   

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,  
        "Direct2D",                 // window class name
        "Draw Rectangle",           // window caption
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        // window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial x position
        CW_USEDEFAULT,              // initial y position
        600,                        // initial x size
        600,                        // initial y size
        NULL,                       // parent window handle
        NULL,                       // window menu handle
        hInstance,                  // program instance handle
        NULL) ;                     // creation parameters

        ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;
        UpdateWindow (hwnd) ;

        MSG    msg ;  
        ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg)) ;

        while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))  
        {
            TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
            DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
        }

        return msg.wParam ;
}
```

Comment: I'm doing a Kinect program, the image only has the projection of the Kinect, do I need to do something to make the lines cover on the image?