# drawing 2d lines in directX9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

does someone know how to draw a 2d line with directX9? thanks in advance

I don't know how to draw 2d lines in directX9 and I couldn't find a tutorial on google so I'm asking here

Comment: Why do you need DirectX9? You could use Direct2D above DirectX11 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868543/how-to-use-drawline-in-c-directx-graphics otherwise https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/line-drawing-support-in-d3dx

Comment: Why DX9? It's so out-dated that there is no reason to use it. Upgrade to at least DX11. DX12 if you're ambitious. DX12-Ultimate if you're bleeding-edge.

Comment: I have to use it because I'm hooking CSGOs directX and they are using d3d9

Comment: Cheat software, I'm guessing. You probably won't get any help here with that. Besides, CS2 is going to be released soon which uses Source 2 which *does* use modern DirectX; additionally, the operating systems CS:GO supports are no longer supported anyway. You're literally wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Legacy Direct3D 9 'styled lines' were implemented in the deprecated D3DX9 helper library via `ID3DXLine`. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3d9/id3dxline).

See also [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/).